# How to get values from hashmap in struts2 and compare it in <s:if test>?

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a hashmap in Action class named param(String,String) in which one of the (key,value) pairs are

```
USE=>1  or USE=>0
```

I want to check it in jsp, using  whether the "USE" has value "1" or "0"? I have a proper getter in the action class for hashmap.And I also verified it in HTML textfield  Whether the value for the key "USE" is coming or not correctly.

I tried

```
<s:iterator  var="map" value="param" >
  <s:if test="%{#map['USE'].equals(\"1\")}">
    <s:checkbox  label="Use" name="use" fieldValue="true" value="true"labelposition="left"/>
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>
<s:else>
  <s:checkbox  label="Use" name="useMta" fieldValue="false" value="false" labelposition="left"/>
</s:else>
```

But it is not working? Any idea will be helpful to me.

Comment: Using proper indentation indicates the probable issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through map to get a value from it. As you doing it now the type of your `#map` variable is not a `Map` but `Map$Entry`.

So remove `<s:iterator>` tag and use just `<s:if>` - `<s:else>` tags.

```xml
<s:if test="param['USE'].equals(\"1\")">
  <s:checkbox label="Use" name="use" fieldValue="true" value="true"
              labelposition="left"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <s:checkbox label="Use" name="useMta" fieldValue="false" value="false"
              labelposition="left"/>
</s:else>
```

BTW naming your action field as `param` is probably not the best idea, consider changing it to something less keyword-ish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:iterator  var="map" value="param" >
  <s:if test="%{#map['USE']=='1'}">
    <s:checkbox  label="Use" name="use" fieldValue="true" value="true"labelposition="left"/>
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>
<s:else>
  <s:checkbox  label="Use" name="useMta" fieldValue="false" value="false" labelposition="left"/>
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape double quotes in Java strings,  but the parameter to `equals` method should be an Java Object. The String object in your case would be

```
s:if test="%{#map['USE'].equals('\"1\"')}">
```

Note, that OGNL uses single or double quotas to delimit string literals in OGNL constants.